# Python using logging in a module

Tags: python, logging

I have tried to find the best way to set up logging in a module, including [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25629985/python-logging-best-practice-for-reusable-modules-intended-to-be-included-with-o/25630154), but I still cannot seem to get logging working as I expected.

My files are:

```
Foo
    __init__.py
    bar.py
app.py
```

The contents are:

__init__.py

```
import logging

logging.getLogger(__name__).addHandler(logging.NullHandler())
```

bar.py

```
import logging

class Bar(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
        #self.logger.addHandler(logging.StreamHandler())
        self.logger.warning('Logger - Create bar')
        print('Print - Create bar')
```

app.py

```
from foo.bar import Bar
import logging

# create logger
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

# create console handler and set level to debug
console_handler = logging.StreamHandler()
console_handler.setLevel(logging.INFO)

# create formatter
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')

# add formatter to console_handler
console_handler.setFormatter(formatter)

# add console_handler to logger
logger.addHandler(console_handler)

bar = Bar()
```

Running app.py in this format produces no logging output.

But if I uncomment the line in bar.py:

```
self.logger.addHandler(logging.StreamHandler())
```

I get the logging outpt, but not formatting as app.py has defined.

Can someone please help me understand what I'm missing?

Comment: Why do you need the `NullHandler` in the `__init__.py` file? AFAIK it should *only* be `app.py` to add the handlers to the packages it needs. If `app.py` should log everything it can use `logging.getLogger()` to obtain the root logger and add handlers for it, otherwise it can do `logging.getLogger('package')` to configure the package logger. It does not make any sense to use `logging.getLogger(__name__)` in `app.py`... since it is not the root logger it will never receive logging events from the libraries you are using.

Comment: OK. I removed (\__name__) from the .getlogger in app.py and it works. I still don't understand why, but I'll look at it when I'm less tired

Comment: There is a hierarchy of loggers, defined by their name. For example a logger called `package.module` is child of the logger `package`. Logging events "bubble up" this hierarchy until some handler prints them. The root logger (i.e. the one without a name) is parent of all the loggers, and hence if you set handlers there it will receive all unhandled events. your `app` logger had no relationship to the library's logger because the name `app` is not parent of `package`, they are siblings.

Answer (score 0):

The application should dictated the logging rather than the library, so if you want to enable the logging of foo/bar.py, you need to add a handler that is different from the NullHandler to it on app.py. The way to do it would be just to add the following line before you instantiate Bar:

```
logging.getLogger('foo').addHandler(console_handler)
```

Then the logging from bar.py will be outputted using the same format you defined on app.py.

For further reference please check [the hitchhiker's guide to python section about logging](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/writing/logging/)

Answer (score 0):

Why should you get output?

From the docs: [NullHandler](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.handlers.html#nullhandler)

> The NullHandler class, located in the core logging package, does not do any formatting or output. It is essentially a ‘no-op’ handler for use by library developers.

The formatter is applied to the `logging.basicConfig()` if you want to set it as general default or the the instance (like you do for `console_handler`).

Now you just have to add it to the bar.logger.addHandler() (through a func f.e.) instead of creating a new variable in your other py file thats named the same as the member in bar.

In essence: you have multiple loggers, if you print the names, you get something along:

```
Foo
__main__
Foo.bar
```

You only configure the Formatter of **main**, not the others.

---

To debug what and if any handler/formatstrings are set:

```
for l in logging.Logger.manager.loggerDict:
    loggr = logging.Logger.manager.loggerDict[l]
    print("Found logger: " + l)
    if loggr.handlers:
        for h in loggr.handlers:
            formr = loggr.handlers[0].formatter
            if formr:
                print("        {} {}".format(l, formr._fmt))
            else:
                print("        {} has no formatter set.".format(l))
    else:
        print("    {} has no handlers.".format(l))
```

Comment: I added the NullHandler because of http://pieces.openpolitics.com/2012/04/python-logging-best-practices/, http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/writing/logging/ etc.

Comment: If I remove the .addHandler(logging.NullHandler()) I get the error' No handlers could be found for logger "foo.bar"'

Comment: @Psionman  The nullhandler is fine - it just does not produce any output. See answer, and use it to debug what/where which one is set to what..ever.